# Intercept Host Traffic via Burp Suite (running in a Guest VMWare)

Tags: networking, http, vmware

Scenario: I have a **Windows Host Machine** in which I am running a VMware VM with a **Linux distro (Guest Machine)**. In this Linux distro I am running **BurpSuite.**

I would like to know **how could I be able to intercept** the http and https **requests** that happen in a browser in my Windows Host Machine, from the BurpSuite that is running in the Virtual Machine?

Which **Network settings on VMware** and which **BurpSuite settings** do I have to set, in order to be able to **intercept the http(s) requests of the host machine from the guest machine**?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community hope my edit can help you understand my problem better

Comment: You will need to configure your network settings such that the host network traffic routes through the virtual machine. I'm not sure how to do that in VMWare, but it's possible with Hyper-V with using external switches. I can only assume such a configuration is possible with VMWare.

Answer (score 0):

1. In VMware you have to change your internet settings to *bridged adapter*. [Here](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Player-for-Linux/16.0/com.vmware.player.linux.using.doc/GUID-826323AD-D014-475D-8909-DFA73B5A3A57.html) are detailed instructions on how to do that.
2. Activate Burp's proxy listener. It should look like that: [image: Burp Screenshot]
   [Source/More details](https://portswigger.net/burp/documentation/desktop/external-browser-config/check-listener)
3. Find out what's the ip adress of the Linux pc by typing `ip addr` in the terminal.
4. Go to your browser settings on the browser of your host machine and change the proxy settings to your burp suite listener (The ip you got from `ip addr` and port 8080).

It should look like in the following Images.
[image: Chrome]
[Source/more Details](https://portswigger.net/burp/documentation/desktop/external-browser-config/browser-config-chrome)
[image: Firefox]
[Source/more Details](https://portswigger.net/burp/documentation/desktop/external-browser-config/browser-config-firefox)

5. In order to also intercept HTTPS traffic, you have to import Burp's CA certificate.
   Go with the configured proxy to `http://burpsuite` and click on *CA certificate* in the top right corner. Then go to your browser settings and import your new certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @UndercoverDog for your answer. Definetly your answer is ok given my question. Although I forgot to add a very important detail in my question which made your solution not work in my case. **I have a VPN/Proxy connection in my host**. Given that, the solution for my case was:

1. On **VMWare** go to **Virtual Network Editor** → Chose the **NAT** you defined → **NAT Settings**… → **Add** (Port Forwarding) → Choose a **Host Port** (8083 for e.g) that will be used to forward to the port 8080 on the Guest → Add the VM Guest NAT connection IP Address → OK
2. On **Burp Suite** go to **Proxy** -> **Options**-> **Proxy Listeners** -> **Add** -> **Binding** → **8080** → **All Interfaces** (or the Host ip address) → **Request Handling** → **Support Invisible Proxying** enabled
3. On **HOST’s Browser** use foxyproxy or directly on Proxy settings → chose the **proxy IP 127.0.0.1** → use the same **Port** as the one defined on the VMware NAT Settings (in this case **8083**)

With this done, now I can intercept my host (that has a vpn connection) via my burp suite that is running on a (vmware) virtual machine.